# Merging partitions - keep data on on partition

Tags: partition

When I moved my ssd on ubuntu to a larger ssd I managed to end up with this

[image]

So I assumed Gparted would allow me to remove /dev/sda3 its empty and then grow /dev/sda5 into the space created but i'm clearly not understanding this process. As I cant find a way yo do it. Data in /dev/sda5 must be kept

Comment: Do _not_ modify the partitions with `gparted`or any other partitioning sotware!! `sda5`and `sda3` ar both members of the same logical volume group, and modifying any of those partitions will _destroy all your data_! And what makes you assume `sda3`to be empty? Your screenshot says that 37.28 GiB out of 37.29 GiB are used! Please add the output of `df -h` and `lvdisplay` to your question, to help you further.

Comment: Posted output in answer section as I could not add it here for some reason. Only had a screen grab

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for replying

Im away from home so apologies for the screen grab of a remote session. Here are the outputs of the commands your suggested

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did all the steps right but the last one:

- You created a new partition (sda3) in the free space. Well, for a really "correct" solution you would have expanded the "extended partition" first and the created the new partition inside that (as sda6); but this will make no diference in the moment, as long as you don't replace your SDD with an even greater one, and that again.
- you created a new "physical volume" (PV) via `pvcreate sda3`
- you added the new PV to the "volume group" (VG) `ubuntu-vg` via `vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/sda3` or a similar command
- you increased the size of the "logical volume" (LV) `ubuntu-vg/root` via `lvextend -l 100%FREE ubuntu-vg/root` or a similar command

Maybe you did that all in a single command, or via some GUI. The result is the size of the LV now being 108.10 GiB, which is approximately the sum of sda5 and sda3.

The last and missing step: You have to increase the filesystem to occupy the free space in the LV. I suppose your filesystem is `ext4`, so you are able to increase that from the running system: `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` (or `sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/root`, as one is a link to the other). For more information, see `man resize2fs`; for other filesystems, see the appropriate manpages.